# Wordpress - добавление блоков из админки

Tags: php, wordpress

Как в админке `Wordpress` добавлять блоки на сайт?
Например, на сайте есть продукты:

```html
<div class-"products List"> 
    <div class="product">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <span> Description</span>
      <span> Price </span>
      <button> Buy </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Каким образом можно настроить, чтобы заказчик мог добавлять такой же блок с продуктом через админку? Где он укажет свой заголовок, цену и описание продукта?
Пытался сделать через плагин `Advanced Fields`, но не то, могу настроить изменения уже существующих полей, но никак не создавать целый новый блок:(

Comment: Добавить с фронта в базу  не проблема (если не важно куда и как именно) см [тут напр](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc/) первые 2 варианта.  Что дальше-то с данными нужно делать?  И как это должно быть связано с теми данными что УЖЕ имеются. Вот этом допиши в вопросе.

Comment: Сделайте шорткод с 3 параметрами: загловок, цена и описание. Делов-то на 10 минут.